# Cannot connect lvm2 pv used for virtual-guest os'es to Centos

Tags: centos, lvm

I have on ubuntu created an encrypted luks partition containing a LVM2 pv which again contain only one volume group "virtual-guests" which I then used with KVM for all the guest os'es. Everything has always worked as expected, however, I wanted to try Centos with SELinux enabled and got it all installed on the same device.

Afterwards, I managed to reconnect the encrypted partition just as under Ubuntu, and running the command blkid show the partition:
/dev/mapper/virt-guest: UUID="..." TYPE="LVM2_Member"

However - pvscan does not recognize the disk as being a pv on this system.

I am quite sure I am missing something very simple - what is the correct method for getting the new host OS to recognize the partition as a pv under CentOS?

Comment: Which version of CentOS and LVM (`lvm version`)?

Comment: Centos Stream 9 with LVM2. The previous system was Ubuntu 20.04 also with the LVM2 that came with the distribution.

Comment: lvm2.x86_64 : Userland logical volume management tools
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : lvm2 = 9:2.03.14-2.el9

Comment: I mean, if you can see `/dev/mapper/${volume-name}`, then obviously the PV was found, the VG was complete, the volume was found.

Comment: The currently found PVs can be queried using `pvs`; you can force a complete re-scan and debug information using `pvscan -vv --cache -aay`.

Comment: The command completed, but the pv was not added.

Comment: It was too much output to paste it here, but I can state it did never even mention the partition /dev/mapper/virt-guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVM 2.03.14 added a new feature/config file called LVM devices, check [lvmdevices man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvmdevices.8.html) for details. Short version: All PVs you want to use must now be whitelisted in `/etc/lvm/devices/system.devices`, PVs (block devices) not listed there will be completely ignored by LVM (to the point that `pvs` won't list them and any VGs/LVs on them won't be autoactivated). Because your disk wasn't present during installation it was not added to the file (the Anaconda installer [adds all devices](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/pull/3600) present during the installation to it).

You have three options:

- Add the PV to the file using `lvmdevices --adddev <device path>`.
- Disable the new feature by setting `use_lvmdevices` to `0` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.
- Remove `/etc/lvm/devices/system.devices` to disable the feature (no device file means all devices will be used by LVM).

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Just one change - it was lvmdevices --adddev <device path>
so 3 d's in a row...

Comment: Thanks, fixed. We need bash completion for the editor here :-)